# Laravel: Output array of bytes to browser in pdf format

Tags: laravel, pdf, stream

I am getting a response from an external api which contains an array of bytes I'd like to convert to pdf.

[Sample response](https://gist.github.com/santosh401/407815de780852bab210356203c27a55) from the api.

So far, I have tried below code in laravel with no success.

`$data` is received from api.

```
return response($data)
                ->withHeaders([
                    'Content-Type'=> 'application/pdf'
                ]);
```

Comment: You can try getContent() method if you are using guzzle

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to force a download.

```
return response($data, 200, [
    'Content-type'        => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="api.pdf"',
]);
```

You could also replace `attachment` with `inline` to render the pdf in the browser (most modern browser support this).